# Explain tendermint mempool and cache

Tags: blockchain, tendermint

Can somebody explain what role of the tendermint cache? How cache and mempool communicate between itself? How mempool of different nodes synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

If by "tendermint cache" you mean mempool's cache, then it's for replay protection. When transaction arrives, we first check if we have it in cache (LRU). If we don't, we add transaction to it and send `CheckTx` request to the ABCI application. If we do, we simply log that we already have this transaction.

- [Reason we have cache](https://tendermint.com/docs/app-dev/app-development.html#replay-protection)
- [On transaction ordering on different machines](https://tendermint.com/docs/tendermint-core/mempool.html)
- [Specification](https://tendermint.com/docs/spec/reactors/mempool/functionality.html)